# DEIS on EC2, wildcard dns works, but app not visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, deis

I'm new to deis, but I've got it up and running on EC2 now. All configs done (followed https://github.com/deis/deis/tree/master/contrib/ec2). I can register, login and deploy an app, but whenever I try access my app thru address given at the and od deploy process, I'm getting just default nginx web. Even when I add any other address like http://nameichoose.deisloadbalancer.mydomain.com (there is wildcard set to *.deisloadbalancer.mydomain.com), it's still the same default nginx web. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, usually this means that the Deis controller can't schedule your applications to the cluster, typically because you've specified the wrong SSH key with the `--auth` parameter. Getting the logs from the controller would confirm this is the case. Log into the machine hosting the controller, and `journalctl -fu deis-controller`. Looking at the logs from right after the scale operation is what you want. If you see something like 'permission denied', this is what has happened. You'll need to `clusters:update` and specify the SSH key you used to provision the servers.

Also, I'm curious how you configured your DNS. If you want your apps to live under deisloadbalancer.mydomain.com, you'd need to configure a wildcard DNS CNAME record for *.deisloadbalancer.mydomain.com to point to the **Elastic Load Balancer's** DNS name.

Hop on over to our GitHub or IRC (freenode #deis) and we'd be happy to help!